# Blender stopped rendering with cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I'm following the donut tutorial and got to [part 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTxBrjN1ugA), everything was going well and I was switching back and forth between eevee and cycles just fine until... it no longer will render cycles in the viewport.  I can still render images with cycles, but the viewport isn't working.

I tried closing and restarting my computer + restoring blender to factory settings.  I'm hoping theres a setting I'm messed up.

[image: Render engine in cycles]

[image: Render output]

Comment: Did you try pressing changing the viewport rendering mode to Rendered by clicking on the top right ball icon in the viewport?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, the first clue was that I wasn't seeing a shadow on the plane even in eevee.  Turns out I was in 'solid mode' and not in 'render preview mode'.

Leaving this up in case it helps another beginner.

[image: settings to change]